# How can I improve hairs on anime character?

Tags: modeling, hair

I'm trying to create anime character with bob haircut, using curves. I've tried to follow youtube tutorials but I'm getting not so good result. For now I've achieved this:
[image: front view]

[image: side view]

[image: back view]

And with shading:

[image: shading front view]

I don't know why, but I'm sure that something is wrong. I can't understand "what" and "how to fix it", but hairs looks too plastic and low detailed (especially in back view). Can you give me advice? I'm doing it first time and maybe I've missed something?

Comment: It looks like "plastic" because of the shader. Look at the head. It has a toon/anime/cel shader which shades the model "flat". There is less detail in shadows and highlights and there is an outline. The outline you can create by the inverted hull technique and often is drawn on the texture partly. I think the hair also lacks of specular. Have a look here: [Creating an Anime Cel Shader in Blender 2.8](https://youtu.be/E3zHGD8V2IY) and [Blender Anime Shader series by Royal Skies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHy5GjQmxTc&list=PLZpDYt0cyiusDdsgdb9FgfT7onV7th8mJ&index=8)

Comment: @Blunder yes, it looks much better, thank you! But I think there is a problem in model. I've added more details to nurbs and it looks better, but still something is wrong...